# Easy Riddles Series Riddle #2

Tags: riddle

This is riddle #2 in the Easy Riddles series...apparently that's what I'm calling it now...

> **What vehicle has wheels and flies, and is made of lots of metal, but never goes in the air?**

Comment: are any of the below answers correct?  There look to be some good ones :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say it's a

> **garbage truck**, flies are drawn to garbage, and the truck itself is.. well, a lot of metal I guess

Answer (score 4):

Since the smelly option is already taken (twice), I’ll guess I’ll go with

> A Moon Rover

It clearly has wheels, and will fly to get to its destination. Probably also if you take it off some sweet jumps. (Not recommended. But if you do, I’d love to see the video.)

It is also basically a big clump of metal on wheels, and doesn’t go in the air, because

> the moon doesn’t have an atmosphere.

Answer (score 1):

> A car filled with flies (insects)
>  I've read "What vehicle has wheels and flies" like "What vehicle has wheels and (has) flies"

Answer (score 1):

May be

> A waste collection vehicle

Explanation

> A waste collection vehicle may contain waste food stuffs and there will be lots of flies inside the vehicle. I saw that today morning as well :D

Comment: Could you add an explanation to your answer? Most waste collection vehicles I know don't fly... (Yes, I know what you probably mean, I just said it for the sake of the argument)